# Listening to Select Menu and display Result: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify

I am using Shopify, but in case you haven't used it, my question should be able to be answered in javascript, it just would be nice if you have Shopify knowledge.

I have a select with options.  Whenever an option is selected, I want that option to be displayed.  It would need to be constantly be updated depending on what the user selects.  I am not sure how to achieve this with javascript.

```html
<select name="car" id="select">

  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>

</select>
<select name="color" id="select-one">

  <option value="volvo">Red</option>
  <option value="saab">Oj</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Purp</option>
  <option value="audi">Black</option>

</select>
<div class="show">
Here is the option you selected, with the Color: 
"Car" "Color"
</div>
```

Comment: Bind `change` event on `<select>`, get the selected value inside it using `$(this).val()`.

Comment: `id`s should be [_UNIQUE_](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't duplicate the id in both select-box. Secondly you can use onchange event of javascript like this:

```
<select name="car" class="car">

  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>

</select>
<select name="color" class="color">

  <option value="volvo">Red</option>
  <option value="saab">Oj</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Purp</option>
  <option value="audi">Black</option>

</select>
<div class="show">
Here is the option you selected, with the Color: 
"<div id="selected_car">Car</div>" "<div id="selected_color">Color</div>"
</div>

<script>
$('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('car')){
        $('#selected_car').html("");
        $('#selected_car').html($('option:selected',this).text());
    }else{
        $('#selected_color').html("");
        $('#selected_color').text($('option:selected',this).text());
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('select').change(function () {
            szData = " Here is the option you selected, with the Color: " + $('#select').val() + '---' + $('#select-one option:selected').text();
            $('div.show').html(szData)
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="show">
Here is the option you selected, with the Color: 
"Car" "Color"
</div>
  <select name="car" id="select">

  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>

</select>
<select name="color" id="select-one">

  <option value="volvo">Red</option>
  <option value="saab">Oj</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Purp</option>
  <option value="audi">Black</option>

</select>

</body>
</html>
```